# Tensorflow : ReactNative: TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetch' of undefined

Tags: react-native, tensorflow

Encountering a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetch' of undefined" error while attempting to execute the await mobilenet.load() function call within a ReactNative application (non Expo) on the iOS platform.

Please help me to fix the issue.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "Test3D",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  ................
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.19.1",
    "@tensorflow-models/mobilenet": "^2.1.1",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs": "^4.10.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native": "^0.8.0",
    "expo-asset": "^8.10.1",
    "expo-camera": "^13.4.2",
    "expo-gl": "^13.0.1",
    "expo-gl-cpp": "^11.4.0",
    "expo-modules-core": "^1.5.9",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.3",
    "react-native-camera": "^4.2.1",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.8.4",
    "react-native-vision-camera": "^2.15.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
  .....
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "^0.72.2",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.72.9",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
   .....
  },
 .....
}
```

Comment: checkout this github issue https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/5571